# Iterating over two arrays and comparing each pair

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Essentially, I would like to iterate over two 2-dimensional arrays of cells, and compare each pair of cells via REGEXMATCH.

I briefly attempted nesting `ARRAYFORMULA`, however this didn't seem to give the required double iteration at all. My latest attempt involves trying to nest `ARRAYFORMULA` inside `MAP`.

Some example data to work on:
On sheet 1 I have several names.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice |  |  |
| robert | bob | smith |
| callum | cal |  |
| daisy |  |  |

On sheet 2 I have a bunch of data, some cells of which refer to the names on sheet 1.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alice went to the shops | derek bought bacon |  |  |
| at home is georgia | felix is cooking | eggs callum buys | bacon and eggs |
| bob isn't at georgia's |  |  |  |
| derek again | no names here |  |  |
| felix and derek | something again | out went alice |  |

The goal is for each cell in sheet 2, to see if it contains any name from sheet 1.

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
=MAP(A1:D5,LAMBDA(x,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(x,Sheet1!A1:C4),Sheet1!A1:C4,0)))))
```

However this throws an error: "Single value expected. Nested array results are not supported." I tried reversing the nesting inclusion, but that appears to be even worse with complaints about different sized arrays, as well as not fixing the original error.

For context, I would ultimately replace the output with just 1 or 0, and use the formula in conditional formatting to colour the cells in sheet 2 if they contain a name from sheet 1.

Here is an example spreadsheet with data as above, together with an additional copy of sheet 2 with the corresponding cells coloured. [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xtoi90OhDhk3a2MSmf0bo1PQPF9DmQfR8ZEndiObq_I/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your difficulties are connected with the fact that [*"Conditional formatting Rules only work on the current Sheet. This is by design. So when you point to another Sheet it will not work."*](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4490297?hl=en&msgid=4492133)

Just use [**INDIRECT()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en&sjid=8686945724376514089-EU#null) to refer to data from another sheet and the formula like as

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"\b(?:"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4"))&")\b")
```

will colorize the cells the way you want.